# table columns data in one row sql query

Tags: c#, sql

```
ID  Model   Color
1   BMW     Red
2   BMW     Green
3   BMW     Yellow
4   BMW     Black
5   Golf    Red
6   Golf    Green
7   Golf    Yellow
8   Golf    Black
```

I have model of the car and colors as table and i want to make it in one row as this. This will display in datagrid in c#

```
Model   Color1  Color2  Color3  Color4
BMW     Red     Green   Yellow  Black
Golf    Red     Green   Yellow  Black
```

--Edit
I have a car model that has four colors. I want this to show in one row. new name columns can be anything can be ID but ID can be changed.

So it can be like...

```
Model   1        2      3       4
BMW     Red     Green   Yellow  Black
Golf    Red     Green   Yellow  Black
```

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to do, and what have you got so far?

Comment: I want one row as model but adding four columns and make this which will be distributed in color.

Answer (score 1):

I believe PIVOT will assist you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT model, group_concat(DISTINCT color)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY model
```

It will give 2 recodes. model name and string of color model. Then you need to process in C# to get individual colors.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), Model, Color
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY Model, Color
```

and then use the count it returns to construct your table.

Comment: How would this approach help to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @jpw I think the variety of answers given suggests that no one is quite clear on what the desired result is :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT Model, Color FROM TableName) as SourceT
 PIVOT (MAX(Color) FOR Color IN ([Red], [Green], [Yellow], [Black])) as Pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT MODEL, [Red], [Green], [Yellow], [Black]
  FROM (
       SELECT model, color
         FROM tblCartable
        WHERE color IN ('Red', 'black', 'yellow', 'green')
       ) x
 PIVOT first(model) FOR color IN ([Red], [Green], [Yellow], [Black])) p
```